# How to let Polkit request root password instead users password

Tags: sudo, password, root, policykit

I'm seeking for kind of old style solution: I need to cause all elevated priviledges platform on Ubuntu machine to request target user/root password instead of asking for calling user password.

I've managed to set target user setting for sudo, still, applications using the Polkit for extended priviledges are requesting the user password by default.

I've seen multiple users of other distros seeking opposite solution, to let Polkit use user password instead of root password, still no clear answer is achieved!

Any assistanse is highly appreciated!

Comment: I *think* it's just a matter of overriding the `51-ubuntu-admin.conf` file - or, rather, preventing *it* from overriding the package default `50-localauthority.conf` in which `AdminIdentities` is defined as `unix-user:0`. I'm not sure the *right* way to do that - renaming `51-ubuntu-admin.conf` to `51-ubuntu-admin.conf.old` seems to work, but so should re-numbering it < 50 so the `50-` file takes precedence. It's possible that either or both methods are susceptible to being overwritten by subsequent package updates though - idk. See `man pklocalauthority`.

Comment: @steeldriver Please consider turning your comment to an answer. it seems to work for others who can then up-vote your answer.

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is controlled by PolicyKit's *LocalAuthority* configuration. From the `ADMINISTRATOR AUTHENTICATION` section of `man pklocalauthority`:

> ```
>    By default, "administrator authentication" is defined as asking for the
>    root password. Since some systems, for usability reasons, don't have a
>    root password and instead rely on a group of users being member of an
>    administrative group that gives them super-user privileges, the Local
>    Authority can be configured to support this use-case as well.
>
>    Configuration for the Local Authority is read from files in the
>    /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d directory. All files are read in
>    lexigraphical order (using the C locale) meaning that later files can
>    override earlier ones. The file 50-localauthority.conf contains the
>    settings provided by the OS vendor. Users and 3rd party packages can
>    drop configuration files with a priority higher than 60 to change the
>    defaults.
> ```

At least in my (18.04) Ubuntu system, the two relevant files are `50-localauthority.conf` and `51-ubuntu-admin.conf`:

```
$ head /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/*
==> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/50-localauthority.conf <==
# Configuration file for the PolicyKit Local Authority.
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, it will be overwritten on update.
#
# See the pklocalauthority(8) man page for more information
# about configuring the Local Authority.
#

[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:0

==> /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf <==
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

So, in order to revert to the PolicyKit default, which uses `AdminIdentities=unix-user:0` (i.e. `root`) instead of the Ubuntu default `AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin` (i.e. members of `sudo` and/or `admin` groups), it's sufficient to either rename the `51-ubuntu-admin.conf` file so that it is loaded earlier or not at all - for example

```
sudo mv /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf{,.ignore}
```

or comment out the `AdminIdentities` entry therein. The former option is perhaps cleaner and more maintainable.