# "Defaults rootpw" for the GUI password prompt?

Tags: password

Usually, I give my default user a minimum set of permissions and no password and delegate all system maintenance tasks to the root user with a strong password. Configuring `sudo` so that it always asks for the root password (as opposed to the default user's non-existent password) is pretty simple: Just add `Default rootpw` somewhere in `/etc/sudoers`. But Ubuntu's GUI password prompt does not seem to honor this setting and always asks for my default user's password (even worse, it rejects the empty password even though my default user has no password set). This leads me to my question: **Is it possible to configure Ubuntu's GUI password prompt so that it always asks for the root password rather than for my default user's password?**

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (with Gnome 3.36.2 and kernel 5.4.0)

Comment: @ steeldriver This question has been asked before https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199006/how-to-let-polkit-request-root-password-instead-users-password?r=SearchResults&s=1|53.8039 It looks like the comment may point to a solution. If so note to  steeldriver: please convert the comment to an answer.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to let Polkit request root password instead users password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199006/how-to-let-polkit-request-root-password-instead-users-password)

Comment: @steeldriver has turned his comments to an answer. Feel free to up-vote the answer. I am voting to close this question as a duplicate.